# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView error

Tags: android

I have been working on implementing a Navigation drawer to my app but I keep getting this weird error every time I run my app, can you please help me fix this error hopefully. Thank you.
this is my layout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/md_grey_600"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <!--<FrameLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->
        <!--android:background="@color/md_white_1000"-->
        <!--android:elevation="4dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="-96dp">-->

        <!--<Button android:id="@+id/navigation_button_footer"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:text=""-->
            <!--android:textSize="13sp"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@color/md_grey_800"-->
            <!--android:lines="3"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center"-->
            <!--style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"-->
            <!--android:paddingTop="20dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingLeft="20dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingRight="20dp"-->
            <!--android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>-->

    <!--</FrameLayout>-->

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_connection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actmain_margintop"
    android:background="#3c3c3c"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my logcat

```
Process: com.myapp, PID: 9693
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.ActivityMainWallet}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                                                                 at com.material.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:46)
                                                                 at com.pocketrewardo.ActivityMainWallet.onCreate(ActivityMainWallet.java:121)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuPresenter;
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                 at com.material.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:46) 
                                                                 at com.pocketrewardo.ActivityMainWallet.onCreate(ActivityMainWallet.java:121) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPresenter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                 at com.material.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:46) 
                                                                 at com.pocketrewardo.ActivityMainWallet.onCreate(ActivityMainWallet.java:121) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Post your app level build.gradle file

Comment: Did you post your whole layout xml file content there? because if you did, then you are missing root layout and some `xmlns` (I'm not sure what that's called)

Comment: Try to update your support library version to latest one. This bug occurs some Samsung devices with specific OS versions.

"Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPresenter" on path:"